# Why do recently edited old questions suddenly get votes?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, voting

I was looking back at some old questions of mine on two different Stack Exchange sites and made small edits to them for clarity. In one case I fixed some bad indenting and in another case I changed a single word to remove some potential ambiguity. And in both cases, shortly after I made the edit, the question received new upvotes or downvotes.

In both cases I'm editing my own posts so it's my understanding that the questions won't appear in the Suggested Edits queue, so I don't know why they seem to be getting renewed attention right after I edit them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Editing posts brings them to the top of the home page - the page you get when you visit the "Home" link in the sidebar or the basic address of the site (e.g. stackoverflow.com) - and the active tab on the questions page (/questions). When this happens, it becomes visible to users and they may see it, vote on it or answer it.

You can see these edits listed in the activity with the note "modified [time] ago by [username]".

Here's what your activity looks like on Crypto:

[image: Edited questions on Cryptography showing up on the Home page with the modified note]

Comment: Perhaps mention that this (effectively) works very differently on a low-traffic site and on a high-traffic site like Stack Overflow.